# Difference between Hangfire background job and recurring job?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

In Hangfire, what is the difference between a Background job and a recurring job? Because cron support is provided only in recurring job and not in background job?

Answer (score 15):

Recurring job is meant to trigger in certain intervals i.e. hourly, daily, thus you supply a cron expression.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => YourRegularJob(), 
    Cron.Daily);
```

Background job is meant to execute **once**, either by placing it in the queue and executing immediately or by delaying the job to be executed at specific time.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => YourImmediateJob());

BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => YourDelayedJob(), 
    TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
```